# Proper way to update QML object from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I've found this [How to modify a QML Text from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062189/how-to-modify-a-qml-text-from-c/9064469) but I've hear that it's not thread-safe to update QML objects lik this from C++

What is the proper way of doing so?

I think the simplest example (a text widget) is enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I have not pointed out that this code is not thread-safe, I have pointed out that your code in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60628889/6622587) is not thread-safe since you modify the GUI from a different thread than the one it belongs to.

I have pointed out that the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062189/how-to-modify-a-qml-text-from-c/9064469) is dangerous and not recommended because the life cycle of the QML elements are not managed by the developer and the QML engine could eliminate them without notifying us, therefore I recommend creating QObject **to obtain or send information** between C++ and QML.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

class Helper: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged)
    QString m_text;
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    QString text() const{
        return m_text;
    }
public slots:
    void setText(QString text){
        if (m_text == text)
            return;
        m_text = text;
        emit textChanged(m_text);
    }
signals:
    void textChanged(QString text);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Helper helper;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("helper", &helper);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    helper.setText("Change you text here...");

    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
Text {
    id: text1
    color: "red"
    text: helper.text
    font.pixelSize: 12
}
```

or

```
Text {
    id: text1
    color: "red"
    text: "This text should change..."
    font.pixelSize: 12
}
Connections{
    target: helper
    onTextChanged: text1.text = text
}
```